# TI83+ evaluate expression program

Tags: texas-instruments, ti-basic

I would like to build a program in a TI-83+ that will prompt for the variables x, y, and z, and then prompt for an expression on the terms x, y, and z. Is it possible to prompt for that expression and then evaluate it? If so, how?

Comment: +1 for TI calculator programming!

Answer (score 2):

TI-Basic has an `expr(` command that lets you evaluate strings as expressions.

There is some information about the command here:
http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/expr

By using the `expr(` command along with the store command (the arrow key), your program should be fairly straight forward to write.

Answer (score 0):

TI-Basic provides you with a set of variables referred to as `Y-VARS`. Any string can be stored to a `Y-VARS` variable, after witch, any time the variable is used it will be evaluated as an expression (as if you called `expr` on the original string). the `Y-VARS` menu is found by pressing `VARS` followed by the right arrow key.

One example of a `Y-VARS` variable is `Y1`, found under the `FUNCTION` sub-menu of the `Y-VARS` menu.

Your particular situation could be resolved using `Y-VARS` like this:

```
Prompt Y1,X,Y,Z
Disp Y1
```

A sample run of the program could look like this:

```
prgmTEST
Y1=?"Y(X+Z
X=?2
Y=?3
Z=?1
               9
            Done
```

In this case, the expresion `"Y(X+Z"` has been evaluated as `3(2+1` and the result was found to be `9`.